# C bit manipulation char array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a pointer to an unsigned char array, e.g. `unsigned char *uc_array`. If I shift the content that the address points to right by 8 bits will they be in `uc_array + 1`?

Comment: Note: I changed the OP's `uc_array++` to `uc_array + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Shifting the content will modify its value, not move it in memory.

Comment: They will still be in `uc_array++` though (post inc).

Answer (score 0):

No.... if you dereference a pointer `*uc_array++` you are incrementing the value of what the pointer is pointing to. However if you do this, `uc_array++` you are incrementing the address of the pointer which points to the "next neighbouring value" returned by `*uc_array`.

Don't forget that pointer arithmetic is dependent on the *size* of the **type** of the pointer, for character pointers, it is 1, for ints, its 4 depending on the platform and compiler used...

Answer (score 0):

Your question only makes sense to me when interpreted such as

```
memmove(uc_array + 1, uc_array, bytesize_of_array);
```

I'm assuming you are on 8 bit byte platform, and that by shifting you mean shift the bits when interpreted as a long bit-sequence of consecutive bytes (and there need to be one char after the array to account for the shift). Then indeed the value stored at address `uc_array` will then be stored at `uc_array + 1`.

However if you do a loop like this

```
for(unsigned char *x = uc_array; x != uc_array + byte_count; ++x)
  *x >>= 8;
```

And assume 8 bit bytes you will just nullify everything there, byte for byte shifting away all bits.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Modifications to a value affect only that value, and not adjacent values.  This includes the shift operators.

The bits shifted out by a shift operator are "lost".

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on how you shift your data. if you do something like this (quint16)(*uc_array) >> 8 then first byte will move to the second. But if just do (*uc_array) >> 8 then, as says the others you will empty your data.